# Set Colorbar match with graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I am plotting my data into a contour color map. I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np  
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import scipy.interpolate
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from functools import reduce

pp = PdfPages('plot.pdf')

N = 2000 
x, y, z = np.genfromtxt(r'100_t_eV_inten.data', unpack=True,autostrip=True,skip_header=1)  

xp= (x-150)*0.6581
yp= y+543

xll = xp.min();  xul = xp.max();  yll = yp.min();  yul = yp.max()

xi = np.linspace(xll, xul, N)
yi = np.linspace(yll, yul, N)
zi = scipy.interpolate.griddata((xp,yp), z/max(z), (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

fig, ax =plt.subplots(dpi=800)

colormap=plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,100)
fig.suptitle('Input Data Contour Map')
plt.xlabel('$\phi$ (deg)')
plt.ylabel('$\psi$ (deg)')

plt.ylim(515, 540)
plt.xlim(-85, 85)

cax = fig.add_axes([ax.get_position().x1+0.04,
                     ax.get_position().y0, 0.2, 
                     ax.get_position().height])

plt.clim(0, 0.2)
 
im=plt.imshow(zi, extent=[xll, xul, yll, yul], cmap='hot')

plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

I got the image like this:

[image]

But the sizes of color bar and graph don't match.

I suppose this is related the part "create new axes according to image position". I changed the

```
ax.get_position().y0, 1, 
ax.get_position().height]
```

Still it doesn't solve the problem.
How can I show the colorbar with the same size of graph?

Comment: What happens if you do `plt.colorbar(im, cax=plt.gca())`?

Comment: Sorry. the axis of graph will change to the axis of color bar.

Comment: you are very much mixing implicit and explicit syntax here which might cause problems if the wrong axes are identified... (e.g. I'd suggest to use `ax.set_xlim(...)` instead of `plt.xlim(...)`), `ax.imshow(vmin=, vmax=)` instead of `plt.clim(...)` etc.)

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example? (e.g. without requiring `100_t_eV_inten.data`)

Comment: In a comment of yours: _"I would like to have the second plot and the color bar"_. I interpret this as, "Your post doesn't answer my question" and so I'll delete my post. — Re posting your data, it's not necessary. The problem is, you apparently cannot fully describe your requirements, maybe with a sketch?